# openvpn starts two processes and connection restarts after sometime

Tags: openvpn

I have a problem with openvpn connections restarting after sometime and while trying to figure out the problem I found out that running openvpn starts two processes (one with `sudo` and without). Is that normal? could this be related to the connections being restarted?

These are the commandline options that I use for running `openvpn`

`sudo openvpn --config config.ovpn --script-security 2 --auth-nocache  --tls-auth key.key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `--daemon` to the commandline arguments solved the two process issue.